# CakePHP ACL-like plugin for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there any CakePHP ACL-like plugin for Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not directly familiar with CakePHP's ACL functionality, you might want to check out [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) by Ryan Bates:

> CanCan is an authorization library for Ruby on Rails which restricts what resources a given user is allowed to access. All permissions are defined in a single location (the Ability class) and not duplicated across controllers, views, and database queries.